# What is the font used on this 70s French form

Tags: font-identification

I would like to identify the font – or a close match – used on this form issued by the French administration in the 70s:

[image: French form from the 70s]
I gave a try at several online font identifiers (myfonts.com and 2 others) which did not yield anything close to be useful.

Using screening of font collections I could find somewhat matching fonts, like Gill Sans or a few other entries in Linotype catalogue. (See the particular shape of the b and the q and a letters, but the pretty apostrophe is not matched and the ç looked very different.)

Can anyone identify that font?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Why are you trying to do this? Alarm bells ring when someone here asks for a font ID when the sample is an official form. I am not accusing you of anything, but can you see how suspicious this looks?

Comment: Ah – I did not consider that… This is out of curiosity, mainly because the font is very pretty and the typography of the document is excellent. I did not think about falsification possibilities.

Comment: I just uploaded a partial sample of the original document to prevent malicious use of it.

Comment: If it's just because it's pretty and you like it, then a close match will surely suffice. Gill sans is almost identical except for the slight differences you noticed, and it's the closest I know of. It certainly has the same look and feel, even if not absolutely identical.

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* Gill Sans, it's just that the blobby ink and wide spacing of the metal type at the small size makes it look different to the digital version you may be used to.